# Getting error: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, smtp

when I test below code with `server = smtplib.SMTP('smpt.gmail.com:587')` it works fine.

But when I change SMTP server to `server = smtplib.SMTP('10.10.9.9: 25')` - it gives me an error. This SMTP does not require any password.

So what am I missing here?

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
import pandas as pd

def send_email(user, recipient, subject):
    try:
        d = {'Col1':[1,2], 'Col2':[3,4]}
        df=pd.DataFrame(d)
        df_html = df.to_html()
        dfPart = MIMEText(df_html,'html')

        user = "myEmail@gmail.com"
        #pwd = No need for password with this SMTP
        subject = "Test subject"
        recipients = "some_recipientk@blabla.com"
        #Container
        msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
        msg['Subject'] = subject
        msg['From'] = user
        msg['To'] = ",".join(recipients)
        msg.attach(dfPart)

        #server = smtplib.SMTP('smpt.gmail.com:587') #this works
        server = smtplib.SMTP('10.10.9.9: 25') #this doesn't work
        server.starttls()
        server.login(user, pwd)

        server.sendmail(user, recipients, msg.as_string())
        server.close()
        print("Mail sent succesfully!")
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        print("Failed to send email")
send_email(user,"","Test Subject")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**IF** the server does not require authentication **THEN** do not use SMTP AUTH.

Remove the following line:
`server.login(user, pwd)`

Comment: Just tried. But still experiencing same error. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I am not entirely sure why it's not working but I have got a few things you can check.

`server = smtplib.SMTP('10.10.9.9: 25')`
you got a space in the ip:port string, try removing it.

- The ip:port combination seems to be from a private LAN address.
  Try to ping this address to see if you can reach it, If you can't then talk to the person who handles the machine with given ip in your network.

  If you can ping the ip, then there is a possibility that the SMTP server is not available on the given port, In that case too contact the person responsible for managing the machine with IP: 10.10.9.9

  use given command on terminal
  `ping 10.10.9.9`
- Also before login and and `sendmail`, you should connect to server using `connect()`, The correct order would be.

```
server = smtplib.SMTP('10.10.9.9: 25')
server.starttls()
server.connect('10.10.9.9', 465)
server.login(user, pwd)
server.sendmail(user, recipients, msg.as_string())
server.close()
```

465 is the default port for SMTP server